# Optimisation parameter scaling in WORHP

Tags: optimization, worhp

I have been using WORHP for a while now and I have consistently noticed that scalings applied by the user to the optimisation parameter seem to have little effect on how WORHP behaves. There are occasions where one wants to make a parameter more "stiff" by deviding it by a small number. This normally works quite well with other gradient-based optimisers, but not with WORHP. Any idea how I can achieve a similar effect with WORHP?

Answer (score 0):

This is a bit difficult to answer for me without more context or an example. When you say "other gradient-based optimizers", do you also mean methods that use second order derivatives, or first order methods only? As far as I know first order methods are more susceptible to variable scaling. You could disregard second order information in WORHP by setting the Hessian to the identiy (for example manually or by using diagonal BFGS with `par.BFGSrestart == 1`).

Alternatively you could try adding a regularization term to the objective function. Say you want `x[i]` to be more "stiff", for example somewhat close to some reference value `x_ref`. Instead of scaling `x[i]` you could add a term `weight * (x[i] - x_ref)^2` to your objective function with an appropriate weight.